# perl die if a variable is set to undef, correct?

Tags: perl

Many Perl libs returns undef if something internal failed.
For example with DBI :

```
my $result = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
```

To simply stop my program in one line (there's an eval at the top caller), since this unique result is always relevant for me to see if all was ok, and lighter than a try/catch, can I always write:

```
my $result = $theLibraryCall or die "ERROR ..."
```

It also works for value 0.

Comment: You should always read the documentation for the library you're using. That pattern is indeed often used, but *always*? No.

Comment: I do agree ....

Comment: `defined( my $result = theLibraryCall(...) ) or die "ERROR ..."`

Comment: Also keep in mind that DBI likes to return number of rows affected, which is `0`, but it's actually `0E0`, or _zero but true_, so they can distinguish between zero and `undef`. See https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#execute and @choroba's comment above.

Comment: yes @simbabque but my question is more general, I mean if I add the "or die ..." at the well choosen statement `my $result = something`, while examining precisly the return code/value/type/def-undef of something, will it be always a good practice ? @choroba `defined` does not seem necessary, it works like this.

Comment: Well, to be clear, many things in Perl return nothing if they fail. In scalar context that's undef (the absence of value) and in list context that's the empty list. That's why the pattern is a bare `return;` instead of `return undef;` The second returns a list of one item. Sometimes that's appropriate, and if you don't know why, it's not appropriate for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```perl
# Dies if f() returns any false value (incl, but not limited to, undefined)
my $result = f()
   or die ...;

# Dies if f() returns an undefined value
defined( my $result = f() )
   or die ...;

# Dies if f() returns nothing at all
my ($result) = f()
   or die ...;
```

As you can see, `my $result = f() or die ...;` will die not just for undefined values, but for all false values.

To only die when an undefined value is returned, use one of the following:

```perl
defined( my $result = f() )
   or die ...;
```

```perl
my $result = f()
   // die ...;
```

Note that these are subtly different. The first performs the assignment before the check, while the other performs the check before the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

### Defined-or operator `//`

Newer version of perl support [Defined-or](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Logical-Defined-Or) operator - `//`.

```
my $result = theLibraryCall() // die "ERROR ...";
```

In older perl version you may use

```
defined(  my $result = theLibraryCall() ) || die "ERROR ...";
```